# Android/Java how to create an array of int

Tags: java, android

I have that code:

```
public int aNums[] = {};
```

And when i want add a number in my array enside a funcion i do that:

```
aNums[aNums.length]=num;
```

But the Aplication crash and exit.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: There must be an error - please show that when posting.

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0

Comment: What do you think `public int aNums[] = {};` does?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use `ArrayList` instead of an array

Comment: Im new in android, i want a array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

public int aNums[] = {}; You have not initialized the integer array.
To avoid your application getting crashhed. The best way to declare integer array is as show here.

public int array_name[]=new int[size_of_array];

now to add data inside the array.simply write  array_name[position]=integer_data;
where position should range from ( 0 and size_of_array-1).

Comment: Thanks, now can you tell me how i can print in a textView the lenght of the array or the first element of the array? To know if i add with sucess.

Comment: Try this after successfull addition of element.text.setText("    "+aNums.length);

Comment: Give me again 50, probably is more easy do with List? no?, becouse i think isnt necessary say the size in the initialation.(Sry my english)

Comment: I could not get what you actually trying to say??

Comment: text.text.setText(" "+aNums.length); output=50 becouse i have "public int aNums[] = new int[50];" and i want the number of the numbers in my array. And i ask if if more easy do with List of ints.

Comment: Working with List is More usefull than array.if you use list then u can get the actual size of list(meaning actual number of elements in the list)

Comment: Ok, can you help me doing the a List of numbers? Im new in Android.

Comment: By using List , you can get the actual number of elements present in it by simply writing list.size();

Comment: Ok but how i declarate a List of int?

Comment: Just give me few moment..I'll get u what u actually want

Comment: I this is that:  List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); and to add is intList.add(num);   print: text.setText(String.valueOf(intList.size()));   is that?

Comment: List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                             intList.add(10);

                             System.out.print("Size of list = "+intList.size());

Comment: That help me thanks. I have 1 more question. How can i "travel" all the numbers with a "for", to compare with another numbers.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<intList.size();i++)
                             {
                                 System.out.print("Size of list = "+intList.get(i));
                             }

Comment: using intList.get(i) , you get the element at that position and then you can easily compare with what you want.Hope This helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You have a Java array instantiation problem. You're not declaring the array size.
Try:

```
public int aNums[] = new int[ARRAY_LENGTH_HERE];
```

That should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add the number at a position that doesn't exist. If you want it to be at the end of the array make sure to do this `aNums[aNums.length-1]=num;` Because the first element is at 0 and the last is at length-1

EDIT: For the last problem that you have you should do this: `text.setText(String.valueOf(aNums.length));` This way you will get the length value as string

Comment: Well i get the lenght that was 50, but just have 1 int. Do you know how to get the lenght of the int inside the array?